# integrate azure AD authentication with asp.net core identity individual accounts

Tags: authentication, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

The scenerio I am trying to tackle is as below.

1) Users can authenticate against my local database using the standard method - Works fine

2) Users can authenticate against social media platforms - Works fine

3) Now, I want certain users who have Azure AD accounts to be able to have a local account BUT get authenticated with their Azure AD. There are solutions for (1) & (2). But I couldn't found a solution that has support for all three. The closest is [multi-tenant SaaS auth](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect)

For those users who should get authenticated with AD will be pre-configured in the system. (I will have their TenantID, ClientID etc... in my local DB). So, based on their user name If I can redirect to the relevant login page I should be able to support different ADs.

I am not sure how to wire it up properly (Or whether this approach is wrong/doable).

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the entire use case, but generally if users are spread across multiple Azure ADs, then the multi tenant approach is the way to go. If users are only in one tenant, then single tenant approach should work fine. On the other hand, the whole idea of relying on Azure AD for user authentication is to avoid user management in your application. If you want to have all the users also in the application's database, then you could programmatically implement a service that could create one based on the Id-token you receive from Azure AD.

Comment: If you describe your use case case in more detail, I could try to articulate a more extensive answer. Cheers.

Comment: my users can be individuals and selected ppl from corporates who are on AD. So, they want their employees to get authenticated with their AD. But some others are just normal users. Thats why I need a way to store individual AD info and based on the user get them to authenticate with their AD or use local DB for authentication. I know this can be done. But wiring it up is where I am stuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user authenticates in Azure AD, your application receives a list of claims to represent that user. You can use these claims to identify the user and *'link'* these attributes to a user in your DB - for example, you can use the *Name* claim to obtain the user Id (that is usually the user's email), and the *NameIdentifier* claim for a Unique Identifier for the user (more recommended as unique identifier), and also *tenantId* to represent the user's tenant/company - than you can wire up these user's attributes in your DB so the user can be represented as one user regardless where they have authenticated.

- [This Guided Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp-v1) is based on ASP.NET 4.x but may help you with the overall concepts - including *multitenancy*.
- [This Code Sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore) contains a ASP.NET Core that shows how to integrate with Azure AD with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: The ASP.NET Core Code sample is 404.